# Length n problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a language that uses the alphabet {A, B, C} In this language words
obey one single rule: a *B* cannot follow a *B*. How many words of length *n* exist
in this language?

**How do i go about solving this and what should i use in discrete math as a tool?**

Comment: You are flooding the system with questions. If you need that much help, you're better off going to your teacher to ask for help, or perhaps hiring a tutor. In any event, ask one question, wait for an answer, meditate on it until you understand it, then you'll be in a better position to ask a second question.

Comment: Sorry i understand.

Comment: This was discussed at meta, e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/how-much-asking-is-too-much) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/610/user-flooding-the-site-with-questions-more-than-6-day). It is mentioned there that at most 50 questions a month are allowed - if you try to post more, the site will not accept new question. At the current rate you would use your 50 questions pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Let $a_n$ be the number of words of length $n$ which do not end with a B and $b_n$ be the number of words which do end with a B.  So the total number of words of length $n$ is $a_n+b_n$.

Can you see the starting position is $a_0=1$ and $b_0=0$?

Can you express $a_n$ and $b_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-1}$?

Can you then express $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$?

Can you solve this recurrence to find an expression for $a_n$ in terms of $n$?

Can you find expressions for $b_n$ and for $a_n+b_n$?